# How can i send information via email to my application and show it in a text view ? (or any other view)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, textview, email-client

First of all I would like to apologize for my English and hope it is understandable.

I want to make an application where someone sends an email and the content, which is a report, should be shown in a text view (or any other view).And if it doesn't work with views then what does? I really have no clue how to make an email client inside swift.

It would be best if the messages remain permanent and you can switch back and forth between the old and new ones by pressing buttons.

I've tried by sending it to a database which is connected with the app but that was too costly. I've also found tutorials where you are able to send emails from the app, but i only want to receive emails and view them. In general I only want to send information from a computer to my app but i think an email client would be the easiest thing.

Here is my code, but i doubt that it'll help you

```swift
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge], completionHandler: {didAllow, error in
        })
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if CheckInternet.Connection(){

        self.Alert(Message: "Connected")

        }

        else{
            self.Alert(Message: "Offline")
        }
    }

    func Alert (Message: String){

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: Message, preferredStyle:
            UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler:
            nil))
        self.present(alert, animated : true, completion: nil)

    }

    @IBAction func VMelButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //Zeigt vorherige Meldung an
        print("Nächste Meldung wird angezeigt")
    }
    @IBAction func NMelButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //Zeigt nächste Meldung an
        print("Vorherige Meldung wird angezeigt")
    }
    @IBAction func HistButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //Zeigt Historie vergangener Meldungen an
        print("Meldungshistorie wird angezeigt")
    }
    @IBAction func SumButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //Schaltet Summer aus
        print("Summer aus")
    }

    @IBAction func KontGSC(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //Stellt telefonischen Kontakt zu GSC her
        print("Wähle Nummer")

        if let url = URL(string: "tel://\(1234567890)"),
            UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            if #available(iOS 10, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler:nil)
            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
            }
        } else {
            // add error message here
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var CurStatus: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var MelAnzeige: UIView!


    //(Here should the information be shown) 

}
```

Comment: It would be absolouteley great if not someone would report my question and then i dont get any answers. Thanks in common.

Comment: you want to make just an email client? https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Swift-SMTP

Comment: no i want an email client that only RECEIVES messages bust isn't able to send messages. I just want a small window where some information is shown